# React Redux store does not update when object is assigned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I have this function:

```
send_data({ pathname, data })
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "src/php/search.php",
        beforeSend: () =>{
            // this.props.dispatch( { type: "set_loading", payload: true } );
        },
        data: {
            type: "write_report",
            part: pathname,
            data
        },
        method: "post",
        success: (r) =>
        {
            console.log("I am sending the data and getting something back")
            console.log(r);
            console.log("after r");
            // this.props.dispatch( { type: "set_loading", payload: false } );

Important>> this.props.dispatch({ type: "set_report", payload: JSON.parse(r) });
        }
    })

}
```

What it does is that it sends some data to a php backend, which then responds with a json string, which I parse to create an object from.

This is my reducer code:

```
const componentReducer = (state = default_component, action) => {
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case "set_report":
        {
            state = {...state, report: action.payload};
            break;
        }
    }
    return state;
```

I know the store is updating as when I print `this.props.report` (the object I'm currently using) it gets something different before and after:

Before:
`Object {assessors=[3], report=Object, risks=[4], ...}`

After:
`Object {assessors=[2], report=Object, risks=[4], ...}`

However the display does not update.

But!!! If I dispatch an empty object `{}`

`this.props.dispatch({ type: "set_report", payload: {} });`

it does re-render the component (I also have some code that checks whether or not the report object is empty and will thusly, return me an object)

Rendering component info (for brevity, things are missing):

```
add_repeat(default_user)
{
    this.repeats.push(<StartMultiple key={this.count} default_user={default_user} users={this.props.users} id={this.count} delete_this={this.delete_this} />);
    this.setState({ repeats: this.repeats });
    this.count++;
}





render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <p><b>Date</b></p>
                <span>Select the date when assessment was performed:</span>
                <input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" type="text" readOnly/>

                <div>
                    (<i>If the select is empty, but you know there should be someone in it. That person may be no longer at the institute. If that person should exist, please notify ITS.</i>)
                </div>

                <div>
                    {this.state.repeats}
                </div>

                <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.add_repeat.bind(this, "none")}>Add Assessor</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const Start = connect(
    (store) =>
    {
      return {
                number: store.component.number,
                report_id : store.component.report_id,
                assessors: store.component.report.assessors,
                users: store.component.users,
                date: store.component.report.report.date,
        };
    }) (StartComponent);

export default Start;
```

Child component:

```
render()
{
    var { users } = this.props;
    users = {"none": "", ...users};

    return(
    <div>
            <p><b>Assessor</b></p>
            <select name="assessor" defaultValue={this.props.default_user}>
                { Object.keys(users).map( (key, index) => <option key={index} value={users[key]}>{users[key]}</option> ) }
            </select>

            <span style={{ display : "inline-block", paddingLeft : "10px"}}>
                <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.delete_this.bind(this, this )}>Delete</button>
            </span>

  </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: have you verified that your `action.payload` is having updated data ?

Comment: @sandyJoshi Yes. But my data is nested e.g. `report = { assessors: [2 elements], risks: [more elements] }` What changes is the assessors names or number of assessors, but it still doesn't seem to care.

Comment: As per your explanation all seems good, can you produce jsfiddle ?

Comment: kind of hard without a backend lol. It's just partially working. It does reset if I just assign an empty object `{}` as explained above. Just not sure why it doesn't re-render when the object isn't empty

Comment: can you show code for rendering logic ? i mean JSX.

Comment: what do you mean? Like the `component render return` part?

Comment: yes whatever is being `return` from your `component render`

Comment: @sandyJoshi For brevity, I have only shown what's needed. If you need more, it's probably best I put the code up elsewhere